# Matplotlib animation with pcolormesh and contour

Tags: python, python-2.7, animation, matplotlib

I'm working with spatio-temporal arrays and I would like to export the results for visualization purposes. I can extract images at certain intervals of time to show the spatial variation. Now, I would like to glue these images to obtain an animation.

With the code below, I have two problems:

1. the animation I obtain only shows the last image (so no animation!)
2. the contours (currently commented) are drawn on top of the previous image.

The code is simplified from the original version but still long, sorry for that! I inserted comments to help understand the steps.

I'm working with Python 2.7.2, matplotlib 1.2.1 on a 32-bit Windows 7 machine.

Thanks in advance!

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.animation as animation
import tempfile, os

duration = 5
timesteps = np.arange(0, duration, 1)
ncol = 6
nrow = 13
nlay = 2
cmap = plt.cm.gist_rainbow_r
CBlabel = 'values ([-])'
plt_title = 'VALUES'

# create output folder
ws = os.path.join(tempfile.gettempdir(), "__ani")
f = 0
if os.path.exists(ws):
    ws1 = ws
    while os.path.exists(ws1):
        ws1 = '%s%d' % (ws, f)
        f +=1
    os.makedirs(ws1)
    ws = ws1
    del ws1
else:
    os.makedirs(ws)

# create  coordinate arrays
x = np.arange(0.5, ncol+1.5, 1)
y = np.arange(0.5, nrow+1.5, 1)
xg,yg = np.meshgrid(x,y)

x = np.arange(1, ncol+1, 1)
y = np.arange(1, nrow+1, 1)
xg1,yg1 = np.meshgrid(x,y)

# create values to be plotted
V = np.zeros([duration,nrow,ncol,nlay], dtype = float)
for d in timesteps:
    for L in range(nlay):
        V[d,:,:,L] = ((np.random.rand(nrow, ncol)+0.5)*xg1+(np.random.rand(nrow, ncol)+0.5)*yg1)/(1.0+2.0*L)
Vmax = np.max(V)
Vmin = np.min(V)
ticks = np.linspace(Vmin,Vmax,5)

# plot initialization
ax= []
fig = plt.figure(num=None, figsize=(11.7, 8.27), dpi=30)
figtitle = fig.suptitle('')
for L in range(nlay):
    ax.append(fig.add_subplot(1,nlay,L+1, axisbg = 'silver'))
    ax[L].xaxis.set_ticks(np.arange(0,ncol+1,1))
    ax[L].yaxis.set_ticks(np.arange(0,nrow+1,1))
    plt.setp(ax[L].get_xticklabels(), fontsize=8)
    plt.setp(ax[L].get_yticklabels(), fontsize=8)
    plt.ylabel('row i', fontsize=10)
    plt.xlabel('col j', fontsize=10)
    ax[L].set_title('layer ' + str(L+1), fontsize = 10)

# plot sequences of grids
ims = []
for i, day in enumerate(timesteps):
    ims.append([])
    figtitle.set_text(plt_title + '\ntime step %s' % (day))
    plt.draw()
    for L in range(nlay):
        Vtmp = V[day,:,:,L]
        ims[i].append(ax[L].pcolormesh(xg, yg, Vtmp, cmap = cmap, vmin = Vmin, vmax = Vmax))
        # plot contours with labels
        #ims[i].append(ax[L].contour(xg1, yg1[::-1], Vtmp[::-1], ticks, colors = 'gray'))
        #ax[L].clabel(ims[i][4*i+L+1], inline=1, fontsize = 6, fmt='%2.2f', colors = 'gray')
        del Vtmp
        # modify axes range
        ax[L].set_ylim(bottom = np.max(yg1), top = np.min(yg1))
        ax[L].axis('scaled')
    # create color bar
    cax = fig.add_axes([0.035, 0.125, 0.025, 0.75])
    CB = fig.colorbar(ims[0][0], extend='both', ticks = ticks, format = '%2.2f', cax = cax,  orientation = 'vertical')
    CB.set_label(CBlabel, fontsize = 12)
    cax.yaxis.set_label_position('left')
    plt.setp(CB.ax.get_yticklabels(), fontsize = 7)
    # save image
    plt_export_fn = os.path.join(ws, '_plt_%s_timestep%05d.png' % (plt_title, day))
    plt.savefig(plt_export_fn)

# save animation
ani = animation.ArtistAnimation(fig, ims, interval=1000*(timesteps[1]-timesteps[0]), repeat_delay=500, blit=False)
ani.save(os.path.join(ws, '_plt_%s_mov.mp4' % plt_title))
plt.close('all')

print "Done!\nCheck output in:\n%s" % ws
```

Answer (score 1):

Looks like there is something wrong with comandline for the external tool.
Go to the directory where the png files are and type this command:

```
ffmpeg -r 10 -i _plt_VALUES_timestep%05d.png -s:v 1280x720 -c:v libx264 -profile:v high -crf 23 -pix_fmt yuv420p -r 30 movie.mp4
```

Should produce a file `movie.mp4` with five animated time steps.

Answer (score 1):

I gave up with the mpl.animation class and invoked ffmpeg using a batch file and subprocess.Popen. It allowed me to use easily all the options enunciated by Mike.